# SSA Sensors in Space - game changer?

Tags: debris, sensors, ssa

I'm curious about the space-based sensor networks that seem to be an upcoming means of tracking Resident Space Objects (RSO).  https://spacenews.com/getting-ssa-off-the-ground/

I'd like to know more about the capability this type of technology can bring.  the game changer is that with space-base sensors, the sensor can continually track near same orbit RSOs with reach-back to other nodes (sensors and Command/Control) for intersecting Conjunctions (CDM).  Whereas the earth-based sensors needs to re-acquire the RSO target every time its overhead.

Anybody have ideas on what some of these space-based sensor architectures look like?  And their capability?

Comment: Why is CDM an acronym for "conjunction"?

Comment: @OrganicMarble, CDM is Conjunction Data Message - [spec](https://public.ccsds.org/Pubs/508x0b1e2s.pdf)